# How to sort a list of Objects by a key value in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of objects

```
movies: Movie[];
```

stored with the following structure

```
export class Movie {
    name:string;
    year:number;
    rating:number;
}
```

Now I want to sort the list of movies so that they are arranged in descending order of their rating.

Every movie has its rating. None of the variables can have a null value.

How do I accomplish this? 
I found questions for java and python but couldnt find one for typescript.

Comment: Typescript is a subset of Javascript. You could apply any of the Javascript solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply you can do this:

```
movies.sort(function(a, b){return a.rating - b.rating});
```

for sorting in :

1.Ascending:

```
movies.sort((a, b) => (a.rating < b.rating ? -1 : 1));
```

2.Descending:

```
movies.sort((a, b) => (a.rating > b.rating ? -1 : 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function of array

```
let sortedMovies = movies.sort((n1,n2) => n1.rating - n2.rating);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

const sortedMovies: Movie[] = movies.sort( (m1: Movie, m2: Movie) => (m1.rating - m2.rating) );